# How to show the console (command line) when using .exe that was made with cxFreeze?

Tags: python, exe

I have a python script that I wanted to make .exe, I used cx_Freeze but now it runs in the background and I have to close it with the task manager.
I want it to show the cmd like in the Python version, is there anyway to do that?
Adding something to my code or something like that?
Thanks!

Comment: That all depends what's in your code. What information are you executing or trying to obtain?

Comment: Just print some vars that I have

Comment: That doesn't explain much without seeing the code itself, but have you tried using `import os

os.system("start /wait cmd {command}")`